# Go Echo bind get nothing from Axios

Tags: javascript, go, axios

I use Axios in Expo to make a HTTP request to a localhost server using GO. I've tested this on Postman and it works fine. But when i tested on Expo it seems c.Bind can't get anything from Axios, the user object is empty.
My function that uses Axios

```js
  const GetPassword = () => {
    var data = JSON.stringify({
      "username": "admin",
      "email": "admin@gmail.com"
    });
    
    var config = {
      method: 'get',
      url: API_URL + PATH.FORGOT_PASSWORD,
      headers: { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      data : data
    };
    
    axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

Forgot Password handler in GO

```golang
func ForgotPassword(c echo.Context) error {
    db := mysqlgorm.GetDBInstance()
    user := &model.User{}

    if err := c.Bind(user); err != nil {
        return err;
    }

    if result := db.Where("username = ? AND email = ?", user.Username, user.Email).Take(&user); 
    result.Error != nil {
        return result.Error;
    }

    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, user)
}
```

User struct

```golang
type User struct {
    User_id      string `json:"user_id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Username     string `json:"username"`
    Email        string `json:"email"`
    User_role    string `json:"user_role"`
    Birthday     string `json:"birthday"`
    Gender       int    `json:"gender"`
    Phone_number string `json:"phone_number"`
    Password     string `json:"password"`
}
```

Error in GO
[image]

Comment: My guess is that this `method: 'get'` is the problem. Generally one should never use the GET method when also sending a body in the request. Either send the data as query parameters, or use the POST method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try using query parameters